# Low priority threads get blocked. Win CE

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-ce

I am working on a application which uses serial port communication via USB to Serial cable, which uses FTDI driver.
My application has multiple threads, with different priorities.
Now the issue I am seeing is, when I connect/disconnect the cable, I have seen that the application's threads, whose priority is less than Normal, will be stuck, and will not respond, where as the normal priority threads will keep on working.

Now the questions are:

1. Is it possible to keep the low priority threads running.
2. If not, then is it possible to recover from this situation, by restoring the serial port. I have seen, that even if I try to recover the serial port from the high priority thread, then also the low priority threaeds will not start functioning.

Comment: It is hardly ever a good idea to mess with thread priorities manually. Why do you feel the need to do that here?

Comment: I am not changing any priorities.

Comment: I meant, why do the threads have different priorities in the first place?

Comment: As a general rule, if any thread with higher priority than yours can run, then yours _never_ gets to run.

Comment: Thats the design. It runs on an embedded device, on WinCE OS. And the application is big, so we have to priorities the threads

Comment: When there are no exceptions, I find all my threads working normally. All threads get the time slice.

Comment: My suggestion would be to comment out all thread priority tweaks and see if your code doesn't run equally well with that when there are no exceptions.

Comment: It's very rare to use thread/process priorities.  Usually due to the nature of graphical OS's and the fact that every app has a UI loop, any thread below normal priority will be starved.

Comment: @AaronLS - you are aware that nearly all UI loops have a blocking call in them, (GetMessage)?  Threads with priorities below normal are NOT starved in GUI apps by default, only by bad app designs/implementations that waste CPU on intensive polling loops, (or graphics-intensive games:).

Comment: @MartinJames You can have a perfectly designed app, but if you use low priority threads, then it becomes the victim of other application's poor design, or the user simply does something intensive like encrypting/compressing a file. Often people choose to use a low priority thread because they believe it is something that needs to occur soon, but not immediately, so they are fine with it only running intermittently when there is idle.

Comment: @MartinJames If that thread is polling device like GPS and uses that information to update a map with your location, then your application will seem broken when the user does something intensive and long running like compress a file, because the thread querying the GPS will be starved until the CPU intensive operation is complete. Your UI will not receive updated location data, and your application will appear to be non-functional until the other operation completes. This is why usually it is better to take another approach which gives you certainty that it will run eventually.

Comment: @MartinJames The main point is, when you take the low priority approach, you have to accept that other factors outside your application and outside of your control can cause your threads to never run.

Comment: Are your threads accessing the serial port? If so wouldn't it be better to put all serial port access on one thread in its own class, and then have all other threads access this serial port interface/class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running with the latest version of the FTDI driver? The 1.1.0.20 release has fixes for "surprise removal".

If that doesn't fix your problem, then try breaking in to the application with the debugger or by writing a kdmp. See what threads in the system are actively running. If the thread that's blocking you is in the USB driver you may need to contact the manufacturer of your device and ask for an update.

Comment: Yes I am using 1.1.0.20 version, but I am still seeing the issue. So is there some way to revamp the threads. So that they become functional again without restarting the application.

Comment: There's no way to know until you find out which threads are blocking you. You'll need to use the debugger.

Comment: I have tried debugging, what I have seen is the normal priority threads debug point will be hit, but those debug points that I kept in Low priority threads, were never hit, once this issue occurs.

Comment: You need to dump the entire list of threads in the system. Look at the ones that are signaled to run. Inspect their priority and their run time. Are there any threads that are signaled that are at or above your thread's priority? If so, those are the ones to focus on. Most likely the culprit(s) will be either in your application, the FTDI function driver, or the USB OTG driver.